# Accessing/controlling True Tone programmatically

Tags: ios, swift, screen

I would like to have control of the brightness and color of the iPad screen in code. I can manage the brightness using:

```swift
UIScreen.main.brightness
```

but is it possible to access and disable the "True Tone" and "Night Shift" effects programmatically?

Answer (score -2, accepted):

I don't think you can as these are private API's & can only be used by Apple.